# UTF8 error message in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql on windows using the guide on this page:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/

And I also loaded their dvdrental database from this site:

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

When I logged in to postgresql and typed \list I got this message:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe5 0x6c 0x5f

I thought there might be something wrong with the database so I deleted it. But when I tried to write \list again, I still got the same message.

Do you know what is wrong? It seems it has nothing to do with the database. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: run `psql -e`  and try again, this won't fix it we'll have more to go on.

Comment: @Jasen I ran your command in postgresql(after postgres-#), but when I tried again I got the same error message.

Comment: opps sorry  I meant `pslq -E` but that probably won't tell you much anyway.

Comment: @Jasen I tried that command but nothing happened.